# What is a person who stalks other's monitor?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would you call a person who stalks other's monitor? I have a colleague at work who looks at my monitor whenever he passes by. How would I describe such person?

Comment: He is a watchdog or a policeman or someone who happens to like your monitor.

Comment: In the gaming world, this is known as ***screen peeping***.

Comment: He is obviously a **monitor monitor**.

Comment: `Watchdog` is somewhat related but it gives a sense of `guarding`. In my situation it's different, it's annoying and against privacy.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Quis custodiet monitor monitor?

Comment: @deadrat I think you mean _quis custodiet monitorum monitorem_. ;-)

Comment: Take a picture of that person and make it your desktop and screensaver.

Comment: @Davo, or do an image search for something like "what you looking at" and pick a suitable meme image.

Comment: @Davo: lol, good idea :D

Comment: I don't think you say someone is "stalking a computer screen" or "monitor", although the OP's meaning is clear enough. To stalk something or someone implies that the target is a moving one, it is being hunted. You stalk/follow your prey until you are at a position to strike. The co-worker is constantly *looking over your shoulder* as you work, *spying, peering, not minding his or her own business* etc..

Comment: My pleasure, I was a little surprised that nobody picked up on this, maybe users thought you were being creative with the language. I don't want to suggest that your usage is wrong, just a bit *unusual* (or non-idiomatic) that's all :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I knew it from the beginning but was unable to think of any other word to replace with `stalk`, my English vocabulary is very limited. Could you suggest a book/online-resource which I can refer to improve it?

Comment: *Check your English Vocabulary for IELTS* by Rawdon WYatt is, I think, useful and readable. Otherwise *Advanced language Practice* by Michael Vince. This is perhaps better suitable as a reference book, but it has a good section dedicated to vocabulary. Online? There are too many, some better than others... for vocabulary, I prefer books. But I see there are pdf files for both titles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If he has no business looking at your monitor (that is, it is not part of his job to monitor what you're doing on company time), then he is a *busybody*.

That is [defined as:](http://www.wordnik.com/words/busybody)

> A person who meddles or pries into the affairs of others.
>
> Someone who interferes with others; one who is nosy, intrusive or meddlesome.

Comment: `The kind of person you just want to punch in the mouth for being so damb annoying. They have no life and way too much time on their hands. They frequently use their excessive amount of time to annoy and monitor others, taddletale for small meaningless crap, butt into everybody's business except their own, and spy on people as if they think they are a cop or an important person or something.` -[UrbanDict](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=busybody)

Answer (score 6):

A term to describe this type of activity is:

**[Shoulder surfing](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/4103/shoulder-surfing)**

> ...the act of obtaining personal or private information through direct observation. Shoulder surfing involves looking over a person's shoulder to gather pertinent information while the victim is oblivious. This is especially effective in crowded places where a person uses a computer, smartphone or ATM.

A slang term used in the the gaming community to describe cheating by looking at another user´s screen is:

**[screen peeking](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Screenwatching)** (sometimes cheating, watching, surfing, hopping, etc)

but it usually is used when video gamers are on a split screen engaged in "shooter" type activity.

So you could call this person a ***shoulder surfer***, or a ***screen peeker***.

Answer (score -2):

Someone who rubber necks. Or a rubbernecker, basically someone who will go to great lengths to look at something which does not concern them ie contorting their necks to see around obstacles.